# MySQL rows to columns based on data type field and submit time

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

OK so I have a wordpress plugin that allows me to create a form on my page exactly the way I want it to. So ideally I don't want to change that. But when it fills data to a mysql table it fills it like this:

```
Submit time | Datatype | Value

        1PM |   Client | bob  
        1PM |    Venue | Country Club  
        1PM | Job_Date | 2/20/22
```

I would like to transform the table into a new table that looks something like this:

```
ID | Client | Venue        | Job_Date  
 1 |    Bob | Country Club | 2/20/22
```

But I'm having a hard time trying to figure it out. I know I can't use triggers because of the way the data is imported (1 field at a time). I basically need code that always runs that looks for matching submission times and adds each row into the appropriate column. I got it to work with a view but I don't have the ability to auto-increment with a view so I no longer have a ID column which I would need as a primary key. Anyone know how to fix my problem?

Comment: if you got it to work as a view, could you just add and extra variable like id or something and make that count from 1 up to whatever based on some sort of order ?

Comment: Ideally I would like to further build upon this dataset in other tables so I need it to exist as a table so i can refer to it as a foreign key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0fc3f/11)

```
SELECT @id := IFNULL(@id,0) + 1 as ID,T1.Client,T2.Venue,T3.Job_Date
FROM 
(SELECT Submit_Time,Value as Client FROM tab1 WHERE DataType = 'Client') as T1
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT Submit_Time,Value as Venue FROM tab1 WHERE DataType = 'Venue') as T2 ON T1.Submit_Time = T2.Submit_Time
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT Submit_Time,Value as Job_Date FROM tab1 WHERE DataType = 'Job_Date') as T3 ON T1.Submit_Time = T3.Submit_Time
ORDER BY T1.Client,T2.Venue,T3.Job_Date
```

Although i can problem with this as new data comes in that is somewhere in between the order it's gonna give you new ids...so it might not work for you.

**UPDATE:** here's [sqlfiddle with trigger](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0c683/1)
This trigger will work as long as Submit_Time is always unique...otherwise if on a different day, if the same submit time occurs it'll update the wrong rows that have matching submit_time.

Comment: I like the design but how do I get it to constantly populate the other table?

Comment: might have to dig deeper i forgot syntax to creating triggers..but you could trigger it to insert into your new table if it's not already in there?

Comment: Well thats my issue atm. The trigger can't work in this case because its inserted individually. unless there is someway to tell the trigger to find the submit time and if its there add X data to Y column otherwise add new.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include an sqlfiddle with trigger..try it out and let me know if this works...remember that submit_time must always be unique otherwise on a different day it might update the wrong rows.

Comment: You are brilliant! It seems to be working fantastic! Thank you so much for your help! now i just need to figure out why my job_date field isn't getting data properly!